# Loop Sub function

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop the below function to retrieve email address based on LAN IDs. Copied below code from an existing spreadsheet.

Requirement: Retrieve "Outlook email address" (Column A) based on "User LAN ID" (Column D).

1. `fldUserLogonID` is no longer 1 cell (it changes weekly) - depends how many "User LAN ID" comes through

Code below:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim user As String
    Dim fldUserLogonID As String

    If (ActiveSheet.range("fldUserLogonID").Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the User's Lan ID and then click on Populate Button"     
    Else
        Call Module5.username1
        Call Module5.FindUser
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If ActiveSheet.Range("User_ID").Value = "" Then
End Sub
```

Comment: When you assign the name `fldUserLogonID` to the range, make sure you assign it only to the top left cell of the 500-cell merged area, not to the entire area. Then you will be able to read the value as a scalar with `ActiveSheet.range("fldUserLogonID").Value`.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by your goal? Do you mean there will be a list that the code needs to evaluate, for example a column of values that need to be compared to the `fldUserLogonID` value? Why/How does the count of your `fldUserLogonID` cell change *dependant on whether another cell has a value or not*. Can you please edit your question to elaborate on these a bit further, include some example data or screenshots and also clarify your code for what you've tried, what works and what doesnt.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Appreciate your help on this.                                             
GSerg - I tried this but because I require the result in each cells, didn't work (maybe I made a mistake -  tried Ahmad's code below and it works with couple more tweaks)                                                                                                                             SamuelEverson - My question wasn't clear - I have readjusted. Ahmad's code below is perfect as a base line though (I needed to include For i=1 to 500) as a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the 500-values are listed in the range `A1:A500`.
Here is one way of looping through all of the values in the column:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim user As String
    Dim fldUserLogonID As String
    For i = 1 To 500
       If (ActiveSheet.range("A" & I).Value = "") Then
           MsgBox "Missing value at cell A" & I
           'You may want to exit the loop when you encounter the first empty cell
           'Otherwise, continue to the next cell below
           Exit For 

       Else
           Call Module5.username1
           Call Module5.FindUser
       End If
    Next


    Application.EnableEvents = True



End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - this helped. Have incorporated For i = 1 to 500 & it works (with adjusted to Module5 codes too)